# How to optimize JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a static dataset that I want to use in a react-native app.

The dataset contains identically structured objects:

```
[someUniqueId:string]: {
  title: string
  // and ~50 numeric properties like
  protein: number
  ...
}
```

There are ~9000 items objects like this one.
I want to access it's value by key. Like `dataset[someKey].protein`. At the same time I understand that 90% of the dataset file size is in it's keys, not in values. How do I optimize file size while keeping the simplicity of reading and filtering it?

Comment: Flatten the object to an array, and read the values like `id = arr[n], title = arr[n + 1] protein = arr[n + 2], ... , propx = arr[n + m] `.

Comment: Define an order on the keys of the identically structures objects containing the data. Map the keys to the rank according to this order. You may the replace each 'data' object in your JSON by an array with the elements in the proper order. Thus you eliminate the keys from the JSON representation.

Comment: this makes it difficult to access data. `arr[n]` is not clear, easy to make a mistake. I thought there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @Teemu Hehe, I knew that could be written more concisely ... :)

Comment: In your code, you can use manifest constants like `const n_PROPERTY_TITLE = 0, n_PROPERTY_PROTEIN = 1, ...` referencing by `title = arr[n_PROPERTY_TITLE];` (the symbolic names can be organized differently, of course, eg. `let map_props_idx = { title: 0, protein: 1, ...}; title = arr[map_props_idx.title]; ` (adopting @Teemu's notation).

Comment: @stkvtflw It's very clear (I've edited the comment), just set `n = arr.indexOf(id)`. Troubles will occur, if you want to change the order of the properties afterwards, though.

Comment: It looks like I was a bit hurry on my edit. Should be: `id = arr[n], title = arr[id + 1], protein = arr[id + 2], ... , propx = arr[id + n]`.

Comment: *"At the same time I understand that 90% of the dataset **file size** is in it's keys, not in values."* yes, that's true for JSON, but not for JS Objects. So, like Teemu, I'd reccomend you to flatten the datastructure down to `{ __keys: keys; [someUniqueId:string]: values; }` and convert it back on the client. so you have a compact data storage format and a convenient data structure to use. An alternative would be to store the keys in an enum `KEYS = { title: 0, protein: 1, ...}` and use it like `dataset[someKey][KEYS.protein]`

Answer (score 0):

Would you give us your whole dataset file ?

We need to know if its an `array` or an `object`.

Whatever you will need to use a `reduce`js function. Just enjoy this link if you wanna do it by yourself https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce